# Can't delete circle in D3 on update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a circle to delete. In this example I want to delete the circle labeled "2" but it just deletes the last circle in the array. If you uncomment the commented part and comment the graphNodes.splice(2, 1), it works as it should adding a new circle. But the delete won't work.

What am I missing here?

```
var width = 640,
      height = 480;

  var graphNodes = [
    { id: 0, x: 39, y: 343, r: 15 },
    { id: 1, x: 425, y: 38, r: 15 },
    { id: 2, x: 183, y: 417, r: 15 },
    { id: 3, x: 564, y: 31, r: 15 },
    { id: 4, x: 553, y: 351, r: 15 },
    { id: 5, x: 454, y: 298, r: 15 },
    { id: 6, x: 493, y: 123, r: 15 },
    { id: 7, x: 471, y: 427, r: 15 },
    { id: 8, x: 142, y: 154, r: 15 }
  ];

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

  svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'graph')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'lightblue')
      .attr('opacity', 0.3)
      .on('click', function(){
        /*graphNodes.push({
          x: d3.mouse(this)[0],
          y: d3.mouse(this)[1],
          id: graphNodes.length,
          r: 15
        });*/

        graphNodes.splice(2, 1);

        update();
      });

  var nodeGroup = svg.selectAll('.nodes')
      .data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; })
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node');

  nodeGroup.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y })
      .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
      .attr("fill", "gray");

  nodeGroup.append('text')
      .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
      .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  function update() {

    if(nodeGroup){

      // Update nodes
      var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes),
          nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
              .attr('class', 'node');

      nodeEnter.append('circle')
              .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr('r', function(d){ return d.r; })
              .attr('fill', 'gray');

      nodeEnter.append('text')
          .attr("dx", function(d){ return d.x + 20; })
          .attr("dy", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.id });

      nodeGroup = nodeEnter.merge(node);
      node.exit().remove();
    }
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6qvx7rn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-bind your data in `update` function, you forgot your `key` [function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

```
var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes, function(d){ return d.id; }),
```

Update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6qvx7rn/1/).

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much... I was just looking into that. Thanks!

Comment: You've been a big help, @Mark. I see now that I cannot update my circles or my text but I can't seem to understand how to handle it. I thought `nodeEnter = node.enter();` and then `nodeEnter.append('g')...` would do it but it won't work. Any chance you could give me another nudge on this one?

Comment: @BradEvans, you need to separate out the things you do on `enter`, on `update` and on `exit`.  On enter you want to just append and set any attributes that never change.  On update you want to add/change the text and add/change the radius.  On exit you remove.  Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6qvx7rn/2/), here I've properly handled the enter, update, exit paradigm.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I get it! Thank you much for all your help, **really** appreciate it.